# Using LIKE for two seperate column outputs

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables where I'd like to compare two lists with a LIKE statement. But I do not want to type in the text string for the comparison. So instead of using:

```
WHERE a.column1 LIKE '%pattern1%' OR  a.column1 LIKE '%b.pattern2%'
```

I would like to tell the query

```
WHERE a.column1 LIKE b.column1
```

I know this is far from optimal, using multiple LIKEs but for purposes of this query this is exactly what I need to do.

Can you please confirm is this actually possible and if so what syntax I should use? I'm on postgresql but can also use aws or presto alternatives although I'd imagine they would be more limited.

When trying the example above one above I am getting null results. When trying to extract the full list as text and using posix or any array functions, I'm getting an error message: 
'invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid'

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
WHERE a.column1 LIKE '%' || b.column1 || '%'
```

% needs single quote because the pattern is a string.
|| is the operator for concatenation.
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying Rahul. Unfortunately this also returns null results. I also tried to use WHERE '%' || a.column1 || '%'ILIKE '%' || b.column1 || '%' but also null results. I'm assuming there must be a way to do this!

Comment: Are you using cross product of wl and ur?

Comment: Hey Rahul I may have talked too soon, I reversed the order WHERE b.column1 LIKE '%' || a.column1 || '%' and I'm getting some results. Just checking through them now to see if they are good. Will post back shortly!

Comment: Yes works fine, marking your answer as the correct one. Thanks again!